# PageMethods in javascript as return of a function

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, pagemethods

javascript:

```
            var Enabled = false;
            function GateWay_Enabled(GateWay_Name) {
                PageMethods.GateWay_Enabled(GateWay_Name, onRequestComplete, onError);
                return Enabled;
            }

            function onRequestComplete(result) {
                Enabled = result;
            }
            function onError(result) {
                alert('Error');

            }
            var MyVariable = GateWay_Enabled('GateWay_Name');
```

Server Side Code (C#):

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod]
public static bool GateWay_Enabled(string GateWay_Name)
{
    bool Enabled = true;
    return Enabled;
}
```

Why is MyVariable always false?
Is there another way to write `PageMethods.GateWay_Enabled(GateWay_Name, onRequestComplete, onError);` as the return of the `GateWay_Enabled` function?
I'm looking for something like this :

```
var MyBoolVariable =
bool.parse(PageMethods.GateWay_Enabled(GateWay_Name,
onRequestComplete, onError));
```

**EDIT 1:**
Everything is working and there is no error for PageMethods.
EnablePageMethods in script manager is true.

**EDIT 2:**
I cannot put MyVariable inside the onRequestComplete() function.
I made MyVariable to make my code easier.
The real code of MyVariable is:

```
    GateWays = [
                        { "Cod": 1, "Enabled": GateWay_Enabled('1') },
                        { "Cod": 2, "Enabled": GateWay_Enabled('2') },
                        { "Cod": 3, "Enabled": GateWay_Enabled('3') },
                        { "Cod": 4, "Enabled": GateWay_Enabled('4') },
                        { "Cod": 5, "Enabled": GateWay_Enabled('5') },
                        { "Cod": 6, "Enabled": GateWay_Enabled('6') },
                        { "Cod": 7, "Enabled": GateWay_Enabled('7') }
                ];
```

I want to use this array in another place.
I can't put it in the onRequestComplete() function.
What do I do?

Comment: Try replacing 'Enabled=result' with 'alert(result)'.  You might be getting back XML.

Comment: Re your Edit2: where are you using this array? You will, somewhere, have to wait until all those asynchronous calls have returned.

Comment: after page load. with user's click on a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling PageMethods is asynchronous: the line `return Enabled` is executed before the function `onRequestComplete` is called.

Try putting whatever code you have that reads `MyVariable` into the `onRequestComplete` function, using `result` instead.

After your Edit2 and comment, I'd suggest you:

1. Refactor your PageMethod to return the whole `GateWays` array given an array of input IDs, to avoid making 7 AJAX calls.
2. Make all this AJAX be called when the user clicks the link, and then put the subsequent code in the `onRequestComplete` method.

Alternatively if this data doesn't change between user clicks I'd suggest you get it on the server side.

There's *no easy* way to ensure the user-click code waits until all seven of your calls have completed.

Comment: @MoonLight Updated, but the advice is still "use AJAX properly and do what you need to do with your data in the `onRequestComplete` callback".

Comment: How-to calls PageMethods ***synchronous way*** ?

Comment: If I knew that I'd have answered this question with it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to re factor your code. now you are doing something after `GateWay_Enabled` method with result. put that stuff in separate method and call it from  `onRequestComplete` method;

```
var Enabled = false;
function GateWay_Enabled(GateWay_Name) {
    PageMethods.GateWay_Enabled(GateWay_Name, onRequestComplete, onError);
}

function onRequestComplete(result) {
    alert(result); // you will get results here; 
    Enabled = result;
    //do something with value 
}
function onError(result) {
    alert('Error');
}

GateWay_Enabled('GateWay_Name');  // you can't get direct output from this method,  
// have to get results from success callback method or onError callback method
```

Comment: thanks for the edit.  your new way is like prev(what is the difference? just using a method). i just want to read those Enabled Parts Of that array from code behind.  what is your suggestion?

Comment: looking for something like DataBinding in asp.net codes.(in javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Did you add  EnablePageMethods="true" in your ScriptManager?

Answer (score 0):

you are checking the value of `MyVariable` before `onRequestComplete` has executed